# org-narrow-to-subtree with auto-fill-mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm not sure it's right approach but I would like to turn on auto-fill-mode after org-narrow-to-subtree. I have tried with:

```
  (advice-add 'org-narrow-to-subtree :after 'auto-fill-mode)
```

But gives error: apply: Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  (advice-add 'org-narrow-to-subtree :after (lambda
          (&rest _) (auto-fill-mode)))
```